# Looking for an algorithm (version of 2-dimensional binary search)

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

**Easy problem and known algorithm:**

I have a big array with 100 members. First X members are 0, and the rest are 1. Find X.

I am solving it by a binary search: Check member 50, if it is 0 - check member 75, etc, until I find adjacent 0 and 1.

**I am looking for an optimized algorithm for the same problem in 2-dimensions:**

I have 2-dimensional array 100*100. Those members that are on rows 0-X AND on columns 0-Y are 0, and the rest are 1. How to find Y and X?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple solution: go first in X-direction and then in Y-direction.

Check (0,50); If it is 0, check (0,75); until You find adjacent 0 and 1. Then go to Y direction from there.

Second solution:

Check member (50,50). If it is 1, check (25,25), until You find 0. Continue, until You find adjacent (X,X) and (X+1,X+1) that are 0 and 1. Then test (X,X+1) and (X+1,X). Neither or one of them will be 1. If neither, You are finished. If only one, say for example (X+1,X), then You know that the box's size is between (X+1,X) and (100,X). Use binary search to find box's height.

**EDIT**: As Chris pointed out, it seems that the simple approach is faster.

Second solution (modified):

Check member (50,50). If it is 1, check (25,25), until You find 0. Continue, until You find adjacent (X,X) and (X+1,X+1) that are 0 and 1. Then test (X,X+1). If it is 1, then do binary search on line (X,X+1)...(X,100). Else do binary search on line (X,X)...(100,X).

Even then I am probably beating a dead horse here. If it will be faster, then by neglible amount. This is just for theoretical fun. :)

**EDIT 2** As Fezvez and Chris put it, binary search divides the search space in two most efficiently; My approach divides the area to 1/4 and 3/4 pieces. Fezvez pointed out that this could be remedied by calculating the dividing factor beforehand (but that would be extra calculation). In modified version of my algorithm I choose the direction where to go (X or Y direction), which effectively also divides the search space in two, and then conduct binary search. To conclude, this shows that this approach will always be a bit slower. (and more complicated to implement.)

Thank You, Igor Oks, for interesting question. :)

Comment: I like this approach. It effectively is doing the binary search on both X and Y at the same time until you have determined one and then just continues to find the other having already narrowed down the search region. More efficient than doing X and Y independantly.

Comment: @Chris: It is definitely not more efficient than doing two searches independently. That's because here the search space is quadraticaly larger. So the theoretical Big O complexity is same log(N*N) == 2*log(N). This solution is just less straightforward and more complicated. I think that this solution is less efficient than two independent searches, because it does not divide the search space equally on each iteration.

Comment: It may be not clear from my post, but I intended it as a binary search. (dividing search space equally). Also, the Big O complexity is one thing, and run-time another. I would assume that this program is x times faster on average, where 1 < x < 2. But this needs to be proved.

Comment: Perhaps. I keep getting the maths confused in my head. I'll agreed that they are both of the same order but I still feel like this method will take less comparisons. I suspect the only for me to satisfy myself would be to write and run and see how it comes out. Maybe tonight... I don't think my boss would approve of me doign it on work time. :)

Comment: And I will try and write a proof. Also should not do that in worktime :)

Comment: Ummm... Dont' tell my boss but I wrote a program to test this... Looks like the independant approach is faster. It looks like this is largely due to the 2 extra tests required to determine whether the thing you found on the diagonal is the edge of the X or Y. As your search area increases in size those 2 become less significant but always enough to swing it it seems.

Comment: Thinking about a proof because the dependant case always uses 2 more checks to find the first result then the knowledge gained has to be better than that which could be gained by 2 extra searches on the independant one. Binary searching is efficient enough that 2 extra searches means a lot of extra knowledge is required and I don't think you get that.

Comment: I think You are head on, Chris. My algorithm could be modified to do only 1 check instead of 2: test only (X,X+1)==1 and if it is false, then do binary search on (X,X)...(100,X); else do binary search on (X,X+1)...(X,100). I tried to prove which is faster, but can't seem to figure it out. They seem really close to each other - Chris, can You verify which is faster in practice?

Comment: I think that Fezvez said it best in his answer that to do this right all you need to do is split the search space in half in each step and discard it. The x first then y method does this in a very simple fashion and I think that anything else, especially something that needs extra checks to determine which section to throw away, cannot be faster.

Answer (score 11):

**Edit : The optimal solution consists in two simple binary search.**

I'm very sorry for the long and convoluted post I did below. What the problem fundamentally consists in is to find a point in a space that contains 100*100 elements. The best you can do is to divide at each step this space in two. You can do it in a convoluted way (the one I did in the rest of the post) But if you realize that a binary search on the X axis still divides the research space in two at each step, (the same goes for the Y axis) then you understand that it's optimal.

I still let the thing I did, and I'm sorry that I made some peremptory affirmations in it.

---

**If you're looking for a simple algorithm (though not optimal) just run the binary search twice as suggested.**

However, if you want an optimal algorithm, you can look for the boundary on X and on Y at the same time. (You have to note that the two algorithm have same asymptotical complexity, but the optimal algorithm will still be faster)

In all the following graphics, the point (0, 0) is in the bottom left corner.

**Basically when you choose a point and get the result, you cut your space in two parts**. When you think about it that is actually the biggest amount of information you can extract from this.

[image: Choosing a point in 2D]

If you choose the point (the black cross) and the result is 1 (red lines), this means that the point you're looking for can **not** be in the gray space (thus must be in the remaining white area)

[image]

On the other hand, if the value is 0 (blue lines), this means that the point you're looking for can **not** be in the gray area (thus must be in the remaining white area)

[image]

**So, if you get one 0 result and one 1 result, this is what you'll get :**

[image]

The point you're looking for is either in rectangle 1, 2 or 3. You just need to check the two corners of rectangle 3 to know which of the 3 rectangle is the good one.

So the algorithm is the following :

- Note where are the bottom left and top right corner of the rectangle you're working with.
- Do a binary search **along the diagonal of the rectangle** until you've stumbled at least once on a 1 result and once a 0 result.
- Check the 2 other corners of the rectangle 3 (you'll necessary already know the values of the two corners on the diagonal) It is possible to check only one corner to know the right rectangle (but you'll have to check the two corners if the right rectangle is the rectangle 3)
- Determine if the point you're looking for is in rectangle 1, 2 or 3
- Repeat by reducing the problem to the good rectangle until the final rectangle is reduced to a point : it's the value you're looking for

---

Edit : if you want the supremum optimality, you'd not the when you choose the point (50, 50), you do not cut the space in equal part. One is three time bigger than the other. Ideally, you'll choose a point that cuts the space in two equal regions (area-wise)

You should compute once at the beginning the value of `factor = (1.0 - 1.0/sqrt(2.0))`. Then when you want to cut bewteen values `a` and `b`, choose the cutting point as `a + factor*(b-a)`. When you cut the initial 100x100 rectangle at the point (100*factor, 100*factor) the two regions will have an area (100*100)/2, thus the convergence will be quicker.

Comment: This seems as a much better explanation of the algorithm suggested by Rauni. But as I noted there I wonder if it really is faster than just two linear searches. It seems it is just more complicated.

Comment: Funny thing what you said, and yes, they are similar. What Rauni algorithm does is that it keeps on searching the blue and red lines until the remaining rectangles are 1 "pixel" wide. Then, it searches (X, X+1) and (X+1, X), which is the same as looking for the 2 other corners of the 3rd rectangle. Now, regarding the complexity, I'm not too sure. I just think that when you do one linear search, you discard half the info (you don't care about the other axis) whereas here, all the info is taken into account.

Comment: @Fezvez: Your comments in the edit of the fact that the binary search mainly just wants to divide the space in two is an excellent insight that I'd been struggling to come to. +1 for that alone. :)

Comment: @Chris : Thanks! Well, I'm pretty pissed for having searched so much for nothing, but I was quite happy to point out the fact that what you really want to do at each iteration is divide the space in two! Thanks for the support! =)

Answer (score 8):

Run your binary search twice. First determine X by running binary search on the last row and then determine Y by running binary search on last column.

Answer (score 1):

Use binary search on both dimensions and the 1D case:

1. Start with j=50. Now the 1-D array obtained by varying i is of the desired form - so find X from 1D case.
2. If X = 100 (i.e. no ones), then make j=75 (middle of the range in j dimension) and repeat.
3. If X < 100, then you have found it. All that is left is to fix i=X and find Y from the 1D case.