# Shortest distance between two curves defined by functions

Tags: algorithm, geometry

I have two functions describing two curves in 2D.

```
p1 = f1(t1)
p2 = f2(t2)
```

where `p1` and `p2` are vectors, `t1` and `t2` are scalars with a value between 0.0 and 1.0.

The curves are both convex with the "bellies" facing each other. They could be rotated, and new functions `y = h(x)` could be defined, such that their derivatives on `x` would be monotonically increasing/decreasing.

Example:

[image: two curves]

I'm trying to find an efficient algorithm to find the minimum distance between these curves.

A possible approach, I think, could be to define a distance function:

```
g(t1, t2) = |f1(t1) - f2(t2)|
```

and then use a generalisation of [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton's_method) to solve the equation system

```
0 = ∂g(t1, t2)/∂t1    // partial derivative of g for t1
0 = ∂g(t1, t2)/∂t2    // partial derivative of g for t2
```

But, I'm not sure if this is correct, and it's a bit inconvenient because I will need the first and the second derivatives of `g`, which I would have to compute numerically.

Is there a simpler, possibly faster algorithm to do this?

Comment: Could you add a figure? I assume you mean two *curves*. A line is straight (which would make the problem rather boring). I'm also not sure what you mean by vectors `p1` and `p2`.

Comment: Yes I mean curves, thanks. I'll try to make a picture. The vectors are points on the curves. When you evaluate `f1` with `t1` going from 0.0 to 1.0, you receive the vectors to the points on the curve.

Comment: Curves cannot be convex. Problems can. And whether yours is convex, depends on the curves. Do you know anything about them?

Comment: With "convex" I meant "there are no local minima of the distance between two points". Maybe my statement about the derivatives describes it better. I also added an image. Apart from them beeing "smooth" and "convex", I don't want the algorithm to rely on other properties.

Comment: Then your problem is not convex. Your problem formulation is quite reasonable (just leave the square root away for performance reasons). Then use any minimization algorithm (e.g. gradient descent, Newton, conjugate gradient, alternating optimization along the principal axes). Depending on your initialization and the *evilness* of the problem, you should take a look at methods that can cope with non-convex problems, e.g. Levenberg-Marquardt, Simulated Annealing, BFGS.

Comment: Thanks @NicoSchertler, much to look up for me :-)

Comment: @NicoSchertler: these approaches look like sledgehammers to me.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Yes, some if these methods definitely are. And I guess that some of the simpler methods are sufficient. At least in practice. But they don't give a theoretical guarantee that they will find the global minimum.

Comment: @NicoSchertler: neither do the methods you mention (especially Simulated Annealing, which his purely heuristic). I guess that by exploiting smoothness of the objective function (Lipschtiz condition ?) it must be possible to derive methods with guaranteed convergence that construct bracketings of the function values.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Correct. I strongly agree.

Answer (score 2):

If your curves are smooth, you can try by approximating them with circular arcs. This is done by sampling points triples along the curve and checking if intermediate points stay closer than a given tolerance to the circular arc they form. (This is a generalized approach to "curve flattening"; you do it recursively).

If the tolerance is reasonable, the number of arcs will be quite moderate (typically 10-20) and you can test the arc/arc distances exhaustively.

Lookup "APPROXIMATION OF A CUBIC BEZIER CURVE BY CIRCULAR ARCS AND VICE VERSA" to get some inspiration.

---

For the sake of illustration, the plots below are three discretizations of a Lissajous curve, with tolerances 2, 0.5 and 0.125 respectively (for 21, 31 and 50 arcs).

[image]
Compare to the same curves with flattening (same tolerances, 58, 120 and 248 line segments).

[image]

Comment: That's a very clever idea I never would have thought of! It looks relatively easy and I guess this should also converge quite quickly. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, flattening is relatively good at approximating smooth functions; approximating with arcs ("bending" ??) is a higher order method and is even more accurate. I suspect that it is possible to avoid exhaustive comparison of all arcs (a related problem is the nearest neighbor circle pairs), but this doesn't look easy at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is like the finding the minimum of `z` on a 3-dimensional over the area of `0<=x<=1` and `0<=y<=1`.  In this case `z` is the |error| and `x` is `t1`, `y` is `t2`.

Rather than use `|f1(t1) - f2(t2)|`, suggest `z= pow(f1(t1) - f2(t2),2)` for its smoother characteristics and look for the minimum.

Since the characteristics of `f1(t1)` and `f2(t2)` do not appear to be strongly controlled, suggest a binary search in 2 dimensions like

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6910155/2410359 or
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6909573/2410359

Comment: Given OP's drawings, multiple solutions may exist.

Comment: Thanks +1. I was thinking there should be only 1 shortest distance, why do you say there may be multiple solutions?

Comment: @alain Consider 2 curves with their 2 bellies facing each other.  Now slide them closer until they intersect.  If they slide even further, multiple intersections occur (with 0 distance) .  Is this prohibited?  Still sounds like 2 curves with their belies "facing" each other - they just overlap.

Comment: Ok now I understand. I only need the distance, so it would be enough to return `0.0` if the curves overlap.